# Android Recieve message from long running thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, event-handling

In the example of a long running thread how do I pass a Message (not a runnable) to the UI Thread?

Basically if I do something like:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().sendMessage(myMessage);
```

How do I receive this message in my main Activity thread as an event?  I know I could directly pass a different handler on Thread creation but if the Activity is destroyed it's gone isn't it?

I know of workarounds like Async Task, Retain Fragment and Singletons but this is for mere understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a Handler that is associated to the main Looper and send the message using that Handler.  Something like this: (warning: pseudocode, may not compile)

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
      case MY_MESSAGE_TYPE:
        //do something with the message
        break;
    }
  }
}

Message myMessage = myHandler.obtainMessage(MY_MESSAGE_TYPE, somePayloadObject);
myHandler.sendMessage(myMessage);
```

The Handler that sends the message is the one that will 'handle' it as well.

Note: If you create the Handler on the main thread, you can use the empty constructor.  By default, it attaches to the current Looper thread.

Also, if you don't want to tie this to the Activity lifecycle as you stated, you could either start up a Service to process the messages, or potentially use an application singleton if the messages have a transient nature.

Comment: "The Handler that sends the message is the one that will 'handle' it as well."  This is confuses me a bit.  I have to have the same handler reference in the thread and the activity?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, a concrete example would help.  But, when you `sendMessage(...)`, a reference to the Handler will be set on the Message and when the Looper runs the message, it calls (eventually) `handleMessage(...)` on that Handler instance.